# What can I import a text file with varying space separators?

Tags: python, pandas

I want to import this `.txt` file, but due to the space between "No" and "Record", pandas is importing them as separate columns. How can I have varying `sep`s? Regex?

```
data = pd.read_table('file.txt', sep=' ', header=None)
```

Data

```
01/01/1933  NO RECORD   NO RECORD   MISSING     MISSING
01/02/1933  NO RECORD   NO RECORD   MISSING     MISSING
01/03/1933  NO RECORD   NO RECORD   MISSING     MISSING
01/04/1933  NO RECORD   NO RECORD   MISSING     MISSING
01/05/1933  NO RECORD   NO RECORD   MISSING     MISSING
01/06/1933  NO RECORD   NO RECORD   MISSING     MISSING
01/07/1933  NO RECORD   NO RECORD   368.00  MISSING
01/08/1933  NO RECORD   NO RECORD   MISSING     MISSING
01/09/1933  NO RECORD   NO RECORD   MISSING     MISSING
01/10/1933  NO RECORD   NO RECORD   MISSING     MISSING
01/11/1933  NO RECORD   NO RECORD   MISSING     MISSING
```

Current import

```
**  0   1   2   3   4   5
0   01/01/1933\tNO  RECORD  \tNO    RECORD  \tMISSING   \tMISSING
1   01/02/1933\tNO  RECORD  \tNO    RECORD  \tMISSING   \tMISSING
2   01/03/1933\tNO  RECORD  \tNO    RECORD  \tMISSING   \tMISSING
3   01/04/1933\tNO  RECORD  \tNO    RECORD  \tMISSING   \tMISSING
4   01/05/1933\tNO  RECORD  \tNO    RECORD  \tMISSING   \tMISSING**
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure that's a tab-delimited file... use `sep='\t'` and it should work...

Comment: [Yes you can use regex as well](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30248128/read-csv-file-using-pandas-complex-separator)

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Gosh, you're correct. :/ Thanks!

Comment: You can use read_table instead of read_csv

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That looks like a tab-delimited file. You can use `sep='\t'` and it should work fine.

Indeed, the default value for `pd.read_table` is already `sep='\t`.

Answer (score 1):

In you case, just use `sep='\t'` will resolve.

But in cases when there is multiples separators (for ex. `,` and `\t`), you can set a regex expression by doing `',|\t'`, python engine will automaticly identify this as a regex expression. So, the setence will be:

```
df = pd.read_table('file.txt',sep=',|\t', header=None)
```