# CSV and separator used in text

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

I'm trying to work with a CSV file that use the separator in text.

The separator used is `,` (comma)

Some of the fields uses comma as well. For example I have :

```
Animals,Weight,Description
Dog,12,brown
Cat,7,it's name is Tiger
Parrot,3,It doesn't seem well, and quite depressed
```

As you can see, the Description column can be quite different based on how people use it.

Is there any way to load the data and prevent an error like:

> Data contains 4 columns, expected 3

Thanks.

Comment: You could surround every field in double quotes, like "Parrot","3","It doesn't seem well, and quite depressed"

Comment: from the above - you can try separating it by ",[^ ]" (comma without a space afterwards) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30248128/read-csv-file-using-pandas-complex-separator

Comment: I don't get such an error with csv.reader

Answer (score 1):

from your csv file you can make a workable list of list like below:

```
import csv
dataList = []
with open('YourFile.csv', newline='') as csvfile:
    spamreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    for row in spamreader:
        tempList = []
        tempList.append(row[0])
        tempList.append(row[1])
        tempList.append(",".join(row[2:]))
        dataList.append(tempList)
print(dataList)
```

output:

```
[['Animals', 'Weight', 'Description'],
 ['Dog', '12', 'brown'],
 ['Cat', '7', "it's name is Tiger"],
 ['Parrot', '3', "It doesn't seem well, and quite depressed"]]
```

You can convert it to a dataframe and new csv where , won't make any problem:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(dataList[1:], columns=dataList[0])
df.to_csv("YourCSVFileName")
```

Answer (score 0):

you should change your seperator. You can use "/" kind of seperators and if you can't change the seperator you can limit your split to 2. That way you can have only 3 columns

Answer (score 0):

Get the csv file with a different separator.

If thats not possible and you know you only have commas in the last column (description column) you can load your data manually.

E.g.:

```
list_of_csv_data = []
with open("YourFile.csv", "r") as csvfile:
    for line in csvfile.readlines():
        list_of_csv_data.append(line.split(",", 2))
```

That approach will be way slower than pandas `read_csv` or comparable functions

Answer (score 0):

Try to use JSON format like:

```
[
 {
   "animals": "Dog",
   "weight": "12",
   "description": "brown"
 },
 {
   "animals": "Cat",
   "weight": "7",
   "description": "some description"
 }
]
```

and when convert it to CSV, also you can use an Interface for this JSON

Answer (score 0):

The problem in this case is that the `,` comma in the text *It doesn't seem well, and quite depressed* will be treate like a delimiter.

I'm using the following snippet to print out the csv-data:

```
"""reading the file 'csv_testfile.csv'"""
import csv
import json


def read_csv_file():
    with open("csv_testfile.csv") as csv_file:
        reader = csv.DictReader(csv_file, delimiter=",")

        for row in reader:
            print(json.dumps(row, indent=4))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    read_csv_file()
```

If you test printing the csv you provided above ...

```
Animals,Weight,Description
Dog,12,brown
Cat,7,it's name is Tiger
Parrot,3,It doesn't seem well, and quite depressed
```

... will result in an "unknown" column like so:

```
{
    "Animals": "Dog",
    "Weight": "12",
    "Description": "brown"
}
{
    "Animals": "Cat",
    "Weight": "7",
    "Description": "it's name is Tiger"
}
{
    "Animals": "Parrot",
    "Weight": "3",
    "Description": "It doesn't seem well",
    "null": [
        " and quite depressed"
    ]
}
```

If the text is enclosed in double quotes however, python will treat it as a text and not as a valid delimiter.

Try executing the same snippet from above but enclose the text with quotes like so:

```
Animals,Weight,Description
Dog,12,brown
Cat,7,it's name is Tiger
Parrot,3,"It doesn't seem well, and quite depressed"
```

... and you will get the result you desired:

```
{
    "Animals": "Dog",
    "Weight": "12",
    "Description": "brown"
}
{
    "Animals": "Cat",
    "Weight": "7",
    "Description": "it's name is Tiger"
}
{
    "Animals": "Parrot",
    "Weight": "3",
    "Description": "It doesn't seem well, and quite depressed"
}
```